# Android Viewpager with FragmentPagerAdapter members of Fragment become null after rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I have an activity with tabs. In order to create the tabs I am using Fragments and use the following adapter class:

```
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }



    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

In the oncreate function of the activity that hosts the tabs I am calling a method (see below) to create some fragments, add them to an instance of ViewPagerAdapter and set this as the adapter for my ViewPager UI element. One of the fragments also has some member variables (Strings, among others). I set these when creating the fragments in the activity using setters.

Here is what I am doing in my activity. (Stripped down, removed the irrelevant fragments for clarity).

```
 private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    SummaryTabFragment frag1 = new SummaryTabFragment();
    frag1.setUser(user);

    adapter.addFragment(frag1, "Summary");


    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Everything works fine, except for when the screen is rotated. The app crashes in the fragment that has the object variables in onCreateView, it turns out that every member of the fragment is null, so I receive a NullPointerException. This is strange because when the screen is rotated, and thus the activity is recreated I am creating new fragments again, setting the member variables, adding them to the adapter and setting the viewPager like before.

I've read on the Fragment lifecycle, but don't understand why this doesn't work, since I am just recreating everything.

Comment: Add the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in Fragment which has some member variables (Strings, among others). 
When you rotate, the frament will call the default constructor (with no arguments) so you will loose the input data.
To retain it you should try to implements onSaveInstanceState
Here is example

```
  Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            outState.putString("key", value);  
         }
```

then retain it like this

```
@Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            if(savedInstanceState!=null){
                 int id =savedInstanceState.getInt("key"); // get the value agains
            }
        ...
    }
```

**Note**: I suggest that you should not use Fragment constructor with some arguments. You should use the default constructor of Frament then put extras data to Fragment by Bundle

```
  Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   bundle.putInt(key, value);
   fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Then in your Fragment, retrieve the data (e.g. in onCreate()) with:

```
   Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
   int myInt = bundle.getInt(key, defaultValue);
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is I kinda want to avoid using that unless there is no other way. I a kinda new to Android development but so far for passing my custom objects to activities etc I used parceable. But I ran into a problem where I needed to inherit from a class that didn't implement it (Observable) so it's kinda tricky. Furthermore, I still don't get how this can happen, since I am recreating the fragments from scratch everytime the activity reloads ad setting the variables. This works fine the first time, but not after a rotation. I updated my question with some additional code.

Comment: Unfortunately even though you think you are recreating the fragment from scratch when the screen rotates, the fragment is created independently when onCreate is executed again.  You need to have a "tag" on the fragment and when onCreate occurs after rotating, "find" the fragment.  You may possibly need to detach and reattach it too.